# Spectrum of an almost Hamiltonian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sg.symplectic-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, sp.spectral-theory, hamiltonian-mechanics

I have a complex-valued block matrix $N=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & -A^*
\end{bmatrix}$, where $A$ is **diagonal**, $B=B^*$, and $C$ is rank-1 but **not** Hermitian.
If $C$ were Hermitian, $N$ would be a complex-Hamiltonian matrix and have the property that $\lambda \in \sigma(H) \implies -\bar\lambda \in \sigma(H)$, i.e., its eigenvalues will be symmetric about the imaginary axis.

Now it turns out, numerically I found for the specific $N$ I have, $N$ has same eigenvalues as the Hamiltonian matrix $H=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
(C+C^*)/2 & -A^*
\end{bmatrix}$. Hence, $N$ also has eigenvalues symmetric w.r.t imaginary axis.

**I am looking to ascertain under what additional conditions (on various blocks of $N$) will this be the case ? In other words, under what conditions is the spectrum of $N$ only dependent on the symmetric part of $C$ ?**

I was able to prove that without any additional hypothesis, $\lambda \in \sigma(N) \implies -\bar\lambda \in \sigma(M)$, where $M=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C^* & -A^*
\end{bmatrix}$, but not the above result regarding equivalence of spectrum of $H$ and $N$.

****Some more details**

If $H$ is a Hamiltonian, it satisfies $JHJ-H^*=0$, where $J=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I_n \\
-I_n & 0
\end{bmatrix}$. The near-Hamiltonian $N$ yields
$JNJ-N^*=\begin{bmatrix}
C-C^* & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker It doesn't work for generic case, thats why I am looking for additional hypothesis which makes the result true...something which relates eigenspaces of the other blocks with the eigendirection of the rank-1 $C$ ...maybe.

Comment: $H$ and $N$ must be similar, you hope for a condition that is different from that?

Comment: Maybe a more explicit result since the matrices involved have extra structure.

Comment: I have now taken a simpler special case where the blocks on the diagonal are diagonal matrices.

Comment: I am unable to complete the argument, but it seems that if $A$ and $C$ commute the eigenvalues are symmetric around the imaginary axis.